# Search depending on tags

Tags: php

I got these 2 tables

```
        POSTS                         TAGS
[  id    -     title  ]        [ pid   -   tag ]
[  1     -  HelloWorld]        [ 1     -   PHP ]
[  2     -    Arrays  ]        [ 2     -   PHP]
[  3     -     AJAX   ]        [ 3     -   JQ  ]
```

and this Searchbox

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="tags">
        <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
        <option value="Echo">Echo</option>
        <option value="JQ">JQ</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

now to my PHP code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    $tag = $_POST['tags'];

    $query = "
    SELECT a.title FROM posts a
    INNER JOIN tags b ON a.id = b.pid
    WHERE b.tag = :tag
    ";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute([':tag' => $tag]);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $title = $row['title'];
        echo $title;
    }
```

but nothing happens after clicking submit, How can i get both `id 1 & 2` titles when i select `PHP` tag in my html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have a variable named $data in you while, its $row:

```
$stmt->execute(['tag' => $tag]);
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $title = $row['title'];
        echo $title;
}
```

Comment: oh yes, sorry wrote it wrong at the code here. fixing it now

Comment: @Axon  also table name which is shown is in caps, but which is used in query is in small letters. check that also. An how's you are creating your connection object,can you paste that code too?

Comment: @AlivetoDie It is small letters, the connection is exactly like here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn ; i actually think my query is wrong or not complete.

Comment: Also note that despite a widespread delusion, no ":" in the keys is required. see my update

Comment: @InnaTichman Didn't realize that at all. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: Found the problem, Was the part you talked about, And there was a varaible with the same name before it with a different value.